# Change volume of media on PowerPoint on slide change

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I tried this code to gradually lower the volume of background music that's on slide 1 (and playing in the background for the rest of the presentation), but I cannot get it to affect the volume. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim bkgMusic As Shape
    Dim bkgVol As Long
    Dim inc As Long
    i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    Set bkgMusic = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Opening Theme")
    
    If i = 1 Then
        'Do nothing
    ElseIf i <> 1 Then
        inc = 0.05
        For bkgVol = 1 To 0.5
            With bkgMusic.MediaFormat
                .Volume = bkgVol
            End With
            bkgVol = bkgVol - inc
            Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        Next bkgVol
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't capture PowerPoint events by naming a Sub with the event name. Here's a tutorial page on using events with several helpful links: https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

Comment: This routine fires on page change - it just doesn’t do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to imitate the 'fade-out' effect in PowerPoint Slide show. Even changing the volume of the sound in the first slide doesn't affect the current volume of the background music.

Here I suggest a different way - using the Windows API called 'MCISendString.' MCISendString provides a variety of ways to control the audio-play.([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-command-strings)) Especially the command(MCISendString setaudio [AUDIO] volume to xxx) can change the volume in real time. Following is an example where the slide show starts playing on the 2nd slide and, on the 6th slide, fades out the audio and stops playing in 3 seconds.

Please take a look and try the following snippet:

```
    Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, _
        ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" _
        (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As Any, _
        ByVal uReturnLength As Long, ByVal hwndCallback As LongPtr) As Long
    
    Public TimerID As LongPtr
#Else
    Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
        ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
    
    Public Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" _
        (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As Any, _
        ByVal uReturnLength As Long, ByVal hwndCallback As Long) As Long
    
    Public TimerID As Long
#End If
    
'audio file name(should exist in the current folder)
Const FileName As String = "bensound.mp3"

'where the audio starts to play
Const StartSlide As Long = 2

'where the audio stops playing
Const EndSlide As Long = 6

'how long the fade-out effect will take
Const FadeDuration As Long = 30     '3 sec * 10 interval

'the default volume
Const DefaultVolume As Integer = 150     

'timer count
Dim TimerCount As Long

Dim Playing As Boolean

'Show the current position
Private Sub myTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim vol As Single
    
    TimerCount = TimerCount + 1
    
    vol = DefaultVolume * (FadeDuration - TimerCount) / FadeDuration
    'Debug.Print vol
    mciSendString "setaudio SoundFile volume to " & CStr(vol), vbNullString, 0, 0&
    
    If TimerCount >= FadeDuration Then StopAudio

End Sub

Sub PlayAudio()
    
    mciSendString "close all", vbNullString, 0, 0&
    'enclose the FileName with Chr(34)s for a long filename with blank characters
    mciSendString "Open " & Chr(34) & FileName & Chr(34) & " alias SoundFile", vbNullString, 0, 0&
    mciSendString "Play SoundFile", vbNullString, 0, 0&
    mciSendString "setaudio SoundFile volume to " & DefaultVolume, vbNullString, 0, 0&
    Playing = True
    
End Sub

Sub FadeOutAudio()

    If Playing Then startTimer
    
End Sub


Sub StopAudio()

    mciSendString "Stop SoundFile", vbNullString, 0, 0&
    stopTimer
    Playing = False
    
End Sub

Private Sub startTimer()
    If TimerID = 0& Then
        TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 100&, AddressOf myTimer)  ' 1000 = 1sec, 500 = 0.5sec
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub stopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
    TimerID = 0&
    TimerCount = 0
End Sub

Sub onSlideShowTerminate(SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    stopTimer
    mciSendString "close all", vbNullString, 0, 0&
    Playing = False
End Sub

'fires whenever the show page changes
Sub onSlideShowPageChange(SSW As SlideShowWindow)

    If SSW.View.Slide.SlideIndex = StartSlide Then
        PlayAudio
    ElseIf SSW.View.Slide.SlideIndex = EndSlide Then
        FadeOutAudio
    Else
        '
    End If
    
End Sub
```